# How to get a property from a List Android

Tags: java, android

I'm using Google Maps Api to get Lat and Lng from a Adress, and I build a class to convert the result in json to Object which works fine, but I want to get just the Latitude and Longitude but I couldn't get. This is my code, they all have Getters and Setters, I just wont put here.

```
public class RootObject {
    public List<Result> results;
    public String status;

public class Result {
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components;
    public String formatted_address;
    public Geometry geometry;
    public String place_id;
    public List<String> types;


public class Geometry {
    public Location location;
    public String location_type;
    public Viewport viewport;
```

And here, I want to get these values :

```
public class Location {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
```

Comment: 1) Google Maps has its own Location and Places API with Android classes, so why would you be parsing JSON? 2) From **what object** do you need to get those values from? And where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Yes, Google maps has the own Location, but what I'm doing is, get the Lat and lng by address, I send the Adress and receive the result. I just need the lat and lng values. [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en-us) is why I parse for JSON

Comment: Sure... but `Location` class already exists. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html and you get that from a `LocationResult` https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult from a `LocationCallback`... https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback

Comment: So I don't need to use Geocoding API ? I can get by the GoogleMaps class?

Comment: You can before searches from the [`GeoData API`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi)... Anyways, your question says you "couldn't get it", so please [edit] your question with your attempt at getting it.

Comment: If you want to not read over the JavaDoc I'm sending, then start here. https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start

Comment: Ok, but by this code that I posted.. `Location ` is a prop from `Geometry` which is a prop from `Result` and inside of `RootObject` I have a list of `Result`, the question is : How can I "navigate" and get that specific value from those properties = `double lat` and `double lng`, I already did the rest, I just need theses values

Comment: Okay, you know the path... So where is the issue? Each `List` has a `get(int index)` method. The rest just goes to your other `get()` methods.

Comment: I did : List <Result> result = rootObject.getResult(); And I have a index of that list, and from here how to access the Geometry property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is really simply "how to iterate a list", you can try this.

```
for (Result result : rootObject.getResults()) {
    Location loc = result.getGeometry().getLocation();
    Log.d("lon", loc.getLng());
    Log.d("lat", lat.getLat());
}
```